# How does this library upload files

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to understand how this library uploads static files to its servers.

Basically you call:

```
netfy deploy
```

https://github.com/netlify/netlify-cli/blob/master/lib/commands/deploy.js#L82

I don't see any reference of it grabbing files from a particular folder and then looping the file system and then loading the file in memory and then calling its API to upload the file.

Where is all of this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`netlify-cli` is based upon `netlify`, and all these files processing and uploaded code is wrote inside the `netlify` package.

1: In [deploy.js](https://github.com/netlify/netlify-cli/blob/master/lib/commands/deploy.js#L115), call `site.createDeploy()` from `netlify` package.

2: In [site.js](https://github.com/netlify/node-client/blob/e31c900907b84fa1d5f446e986577c315ccd5398/lib/site.js#L197), [`createDeploy()`](https://github.com/netlify/node-client/blob/e31c900907b84fa1d5f446e986577c315ccd5398/lib/site.js#L197) call [`deployFromDir`](https://github.com/netlify/node-client/blob/e31c900907b84fa1d5f446e986577c315ccd5398/lib/site.js#L68), [`deployFromZip`](https://github.com/netlify/node-client/blob/e31c900907b84fa1d5f446e986577c315ccd5398/lib/site.js#L105), these two methods are where all these files processing and uploaded happened